Sending Angular Positions to ABB Robot Using ROS Noetic and EGM
I am new to using ROS Noetic and I am trying to integrate an ABB robot with ROS using the abb_robot_driver package and EGM. My goal is to send angular positions to the robot's joints directly through ROS, but I am having trouble understanding how to achieve this communication.
I want to send commands for angular positions to the robot joints using variables jointtarget.
I have tried "ex2_rws_and_egm_6axis_robot" in the GitHub repository but it doesn't work.
I am using python to create the nodes to send positions.
What is the correct way to configure a ROS node to use abb_robot_driver to send movement commands to the robot joints?
How can I use the EGM module to send angular positions to the joints? What are the necessary configurations and steps?
What specific resources or documentation should I consult to get more information on integrating ROS with the EGM module and abb_robot_driver?
